Melhor forma de acessar sublistas para realizar operações de estatísticas
Por uma questão estatística, preciso fazer algumas verificações da maior média de valores dentro de determinados intervalos de uma lista de números inteiros.
Exemplificado em uma pequena lista, na busca da maior média de 3 registros seguidos seria:

Já possuo um método que criei que funciona perfeitamente, porém estou buscando melhorias em sua performance, já que as listas em questões normalmente possuim em média 30 mil registros e preciso verificar uma série de intervalos diferentes(atualmente já rodam em várias treads paralelamente), logo acaba sendo um processo o tanto quanto demorado em determinadas situações.
Atualmente quebro a lista principal em uma "sublista" do intervalo desejado e utilizo a função statistics.mean para o cálculo da média:
import statistics

def retorna_maior_intervalo(lista, numero_registros):
    maior_media = 0
    inicio_maior = 0
    fim_maior = 0
    for x in range(len(lista)):
        limite = x + numero_registros
        if limite > len(lista):
            break
        sublista = lista[x:limite]
        media_atual = statistics.mean(sublista)
        if media_atual > maior_media:
            maior_media = media_atual
            inicio_maior = x
            fim_maior = limite - 1
    return maior_media, inicio_maior, fim_maior

Simples exemplo da utilização do método:
lista = [100, 100, 110, 130, 108, 100, 133, 142, 0, 113]
media, inicio, fim = retorna_maior_intervalo(lista, 3)
print(f"valor médio do intervalo: {media}")
print(f"posição inicial: {inicio}")
print(f"posição final: {fim}")

Existiria uma solução mais performática para a realização deste cálculo?
Atualizações:
Conforme o comentário do Augusto, verifiquei algumas alternativas, implementando sua solução com iterador e map, notei uma melhora razoável na performance com uma lista maior, porém na hora que troquei a formula para utilizar a biblioteca statistics achei uma das raízes do meu problema: a função mean da biblioteca statistics é extremamente lenta.
No stackoverflow achei uma pergunta bem popular perguntando esta questão de performance do statistics.mean, uma das respostas utilizou uma frase que explica bem:

O módulo statistics não foi feito para performance, mas sim para
precisão

Como o processo que estou trabalhando, preciso de uma precisão grosseira, aonde de qualquer forma o valor sera arredondado para o inteiro mais próximo, alterei meu método para usar um simples  sum(sublista) / len(sublista)
Com esta simples alteração o código esta rodando em menos de 1/20 do tempo original.
A solução usando o iterador e map ficou muito próximo, mas levemente mais lenta.
Após as sugestões dos comentários, o procedimento esta da seguinte forma:
def retorna_maior_intervalo(lista, numero_registros):
    maior_media = 0
    posicao_maior = 0
    for x in range(len(lista) - numero_registros + 1):
        limite = x + numero_registros
        sublista = lista[x:limite]
        media_atual = sum(sublista) / len(sublista) 
        if media_atual > maior_media:
            maior_media = media_atual
            posicao_maior = x
    return maior_media, posicao_maior


Isto responde à sua pergunta? Python, como calcular a média de uma lista de 5 em 5 elementos?, Veja que pode aplicar qualquer umas das soluções ao seu problema e da lista de médias resultantes é só aplicar o builtin max() para obter a maior média.

@AugustoVasques, verifiquei as respostas da publicação, até cheguei a implementar usando sua solução com interador e map, não resolveu diretamente meu problema de performance, mas me ajudou muito a notar um problema no meu código, vou adicionar um adendo na minha pergunta explicando uma das melhorias encontradas e testes usando sua solução.

Outro detalhe é que no for pode trocar por range(len(lista) - numero_registros + 1) - assim, vc garante que vai só até onde precisa, podendo retirar o if limite > len(lista). Assim, não precisa mais da variável limite, pois pra sublista pode usar lista[x:x + numero_registros]. E tb não precisa do fim_maior, pois no final basta trocar para return maior_media, inicio_maior, inicio_maior + numero_registros - 1. Dito isso, fiz uns testes simples e usar sum é bem mais rápido mesmo: https://ideone.com/69O4nQ

@hkotsubo, obrigado pelas dicas, realmente ficava meio redundante estas verificações que fiz, realizei a alteração aqui, além do código ficar mais limpo, o tempo de execução ficou em média 3% mais rápido.

Como você estar usando uma quantidade fixa de registros (k), você pode apenas comparar a soma de cada sublista em vez de calcular a média e compara-las, já que fazer divisão tem um certo custo.
def retorna_maior_intervalo_sum2(lista, numero_registros):
    soma_aux = sum(lista[:numero_registros])
    soma = soma_aux
    inicio_maior = 0
    for x in range(1, len(lista)-numero_registros+1):
        soma_aux = soma_aux - lista[x-1] + lista[x+numero_registros-1]
        if soma_aux > soma:
            inicio_maior = x
            soma = soma_aux
    return soma/numero_registros, inicio_maior, inicio_maior + numero_registros - 1

Vou estar usando a resposta do @hkotsubo nesse link e os demais comentários como base para testar o tempo de execução.
Vou usar a seguinte lista para forçar sempre a execução do que tem dentro do if para toda sublista, apenas para usar a máxima capacidade:
gera_lista = lambda N: list(range(1, N+1))
lista = gera_lista(1_000_000) # -> sempre a maior média/soma, a cada sublista, estará no fim da lista
lista.reverse() # -> sempre a maior média/soma, a cada sublista, estará no inicio da lista

Comparando com a função retorna_maior_intervalo_sum aqui, pois é a que possuí o melhor tempo:
# input
lista = gera_lista(1_000_000)
params = { 'number': 100, 'globals': globals() }
print('{:.<12} {}'.format('sum', timeit('retorna_maior_intervalo_sum(lista, 3)', **params)))
print('{:.<12} {}'.format('sum2', timeit('retorna_maior_intervalo_sum2(lista, 3)', **params)))

# output
sum......... 24.89773669999704
sum2........ 14.929011599997466

Como um adicional, Python puro e performance não costumam andar muito juntos. Então por motivos de curiosidade implementei a função retorna_maior_intervalo_sum2 usando CPython em C++.
PS: Nessa implementação aceita apenas valores inteiros.
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef long int tp_list;
typedef unsigned long int tp_index;

void max_mean(std::vector<tp_list>& arr, double& mean, tp_index& start_id, tp_index& end_id, tp_index n, tp_index k) {
    if (n < k) return;

    double sum_aux = 0;

    for (tp_index i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        sum_aux += static_cast<double>(arr[i]);
    }

    double sum = sum_aux;

    start_id = 0;
    end_id = k - 1;

    for (tp_index x = 1; x <= n - k; ++x) {
        sum_aux = sum_aux - static_cast<double>(arr[x - 1]) + static_cast<double>(arr[x + k-1]);
        if (sum_aux > sum) {
            sum = sum_aux;
            start_id = x;
            end_id = x + k - 1;
        }
    }
    mean = sum/k;
}

static PyObject *retorna_maior_intervalo(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    PyObject* k_obj = Py_None;
    PyObject* lista_obj = Py_None;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!O", &PyList_Type, &lista_obj, &k_obj)) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    if(!PyLong_Check(k_obj)) {
        return PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError, "O paramentro k deve ser do tipo inteiro >=1, no entanto foi dado %s", Py_TYPE(k_obj)->tp_name);
    }

    tp_index k = PyLong_AsUnsignedLong(k_obj);
    if(k == static_cast<tp_index>(-1) && PyErr_Occurred()) {
        PyErr_Clear();
        return PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError, "O paramentro k deve ser do tipo inteiro >=1, no entanto foi dado %lld", PyLong_AsLongLong(k_obj));
    }

    if (k < 1) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "O parametro \"k\" deve ser um inteiro >=1.");
        return nullptr;
    }

    std::vector<tp_list> lista;
    Py_ssize_t lista_tam = PyList_Size(lista_obj);

    for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < lista_tam; ++i) {
        PyObject* value = PyList_GetItem(lista_obj, i);
        if(!PyLong_Check(value)) {
            PyErr_Clear();
            return PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError, "A lista deve ter valores do tipo int, no entanto foi dado %s", Py_TYPE(value)->tp_name);
        }
        lista.push_back(PyLong_AsLong(value));
    }

    tp_index n = static_cast<tp_index>(lista.size());
    double mean = -1;
    tp_index start_id = 0;
    tp_index end_id = 0;

    max_mean(lista, mean, start_id, end_id, n, k);

    return Py_BuildValue("dII", mean, start_id, end_id);
}

//===================PYTHON_MODULE_DEFINITION==========================

static PyMethodDef methdef = {
        .ml_name = "retorna_maior_intervalo",
        .ml_meth = static_cast<PyCFunction>(retorna_maior_intervalo),
        .ml_flags = METH_VARARGS,
        .ml_doc = PyDoc_STR(
            "Encontra a maior média a cada \"k\" termos em sequência.\n"
            "\tlista: sequência do tipo int\n"
            "\tk: quantidade (int >= 1) de termos para se calcular a média em sequência\n"
        )
};

static PyMethodDef all_methods[] = {
    methdef,
    {nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr} /* Sentinel */
};

static PyModuleDef c_rmi_module = {
    .m_base = PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    .m_name = "c_rmi",
    .m_size = -1,
    .m_methods = all_methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_c_rmi(void){
    Py_Initialize();
    return PyModule_Create(&c_rmi_module);
}

A função retorna_maior_intervalo_original, é a função dada de exemplo na pergunta.
# input
lista = gera_lista(1_000_000)
params = {'number': 100, 'globals': globals()}
fmt = "{:.<12} {}".format
print(fmt('original', timeit('retorna_maior_intervalo_original(lista, 3)', **params)))
print(fmt('sum', timeit('retorna_maior_intervalo_sum(lista, 3)', **params)))
print(fmt('sum2', timeit('retorna_maior_intervalo_sum2(lista, 3)', **params)))
print(fmt('cpython', timeit('rmi.retorna_maior_intervalo(lista, 3)', **params)))

# output
original.... 574.7887451999995
sum......... 25.224075600002834
sum2........ 15.296571599996241
cpython..... 1.1160187000059523


Pode-se encontrar aqui os testes feito, assim como a implementação do código CPython.

O link do benchmark mostra apenas os testes para statistics.mean(), globals().sum() e numpy.mean()

Mesmo esta não sendo uma pergunta que buscava uma resposta definitiva, precisei marcar esta como resposta correta! Foi uma jogada de mestre evitar criar uma sublista e fazer os cálculos subtraindo o item anterior e somando o subsequente. Testando no meu cenário mais crítico o tempo de execução caiu para 7 segundos, algo que antes levava alguns minutos para realização dos cálculos. Já a implementação em C++ é algo que talvez utilize num futuro se minha aplicação escalar para algo maior e precisar de mais performance ainda . Agradeço muito pela formulação desta ótima resposta!

Uma vez que você não precisa, aparentemente, guardar 'sublista' em memória, pode economizar uma cópia do slice passando lista[x:limite] diretamente na função 'mean'.
media_atual = statistics.mean(lista[x:limite])

Pode ser uma pequena melhoria. Veja se isso vai melhorar o desempenho, porque sublista = lista[x:limite] vai executar uma operação de cópia desse slice a cada interação, que pode não ser necessária (pelo código exibido, ela só é necessária para passar como parâmetro para a função.

Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas na Central de Ajuda.
